# Boot process stuck on Started Light Display Manager

Tags: boot

I installed **bumblebee** and **TLP**. The next time I booted the computer got stuck on the message `Started Light Display Manager`. I managed to remove bumblebee and TLP from a root prompt, but I had to use the option repair packages to make the filesystem writeable. Nothing changed. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot in the `recovery` mode (By holding shift key on BIOS prompt).
2. Select the option to drop into a Root Session.
3. Run `mount -o remount,rw /` to mount your drive in a `RW` mode.
4. Now, analyze your problem with `lightdm`. You can also try setting a different DM using `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` or install the lighter xdm.

Comment: It works now. Bumblebee and TLP hadn't been uninstalled. What you said about remounting helped.